# Options for Internal SSD Upgrade

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-installation, clone, windows-11

I currently have a 256GB internal SSD in my laptop, but it isn't enough. I have just ordered a 500GB one, and that will be enough (at least for now).

I have looked up a few things on how to "clone" the SSDs, but I don't have an adapter to do that with.

- Is there a way to save my current Windows state into an ISO file, and then create a bootable USB drive of that ISO, and so when I use it to install Windows again, it will have all my stuff?
- Is there a different easy way that doesn't involve special adapters?
- Or will I just need to copy my files that I need, install windows on the new SSD, copy my files onto it, and then reinstall my programs?
- Or would it be best just to get an adapter for the SSD and clone it?

I don't really have any experience with this, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There exists numerous third-party programs that can create an image of your current drive and then restore it on another drive. The destination drive for the image would have to be large enough to contain the image. This will allow you to capture the image, change the drive, and boot into the supported environment to restore the image on the new drive

Comment: Remember that when you clone a drive you also clone the errors and imperfections. If your system works perfectly week in and out, then by all means clone it.

Comment: I think the best option is still to buy a USB 3 SSD adapter.

Comment: Clonezilla would allow you to create a bootable iso image and backup to any other USB or network device. Personally I prefer the extra adapter because you can do the entire job in one go.